# listview and recyclerview doesnot wrap content with count

Tags: android, xml, listview

this is my layout for the same. my issue is, the list view in it is not increase the height with item count. 
when I used wrap_content a given height like 210 pixel its shows the data... when I set height as wrap_content, it is showing only one item.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rl_createPro_option"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please provide option-wise price:"/>
    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv_createPro"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rg_createPro"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Option highlight??"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="yes"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="no"/>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

please help me!!

Comment: Please read the [ask] section, under which circumstances you should use tags as "*asap*" and edit your question!

Comment: Please add layout file for list item

Comment: @BenRoob i have done it.

Comment: @SurajVaishnav i have solved the issue with the comment mention below.. thank you for your time and interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of your linearlayout with `vertical` orientation its keeping space for the lower `views` like `radioGroups` .Set height of listview dynamically use

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(final ListView listView) {
    listView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter == null) {
                return;
            }
            int totalHeight = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();
            int listWidth = listView.getMeasuredWidth();
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
                listItem.measure(
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));


                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                Log.d("listItemHeight " + listItem.getMeasuredHeight(), "********");
            }

            Log.d("totalHeight " + totalHeight, "********");

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = (totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1)));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
            listView.requestLayout();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: so how can i over come this??

Comment: just use this method in `listview ` and set `height` as `match_parent` after `listview.setAdapter()` use `setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(yourListView);`

Comment: thank you very much.. this really helped.. can i do the same for Recycle view also?? because I am facing the same issue there also???

Comment: yes just change accordingly those that are `listview` and if your question is answered please mark as answered ... with `recyclerView`

Comment: Thank you so much. i will do it.