# NestedScrollView does not scroll

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview

I have two list views in nested-scroll view and I want both the list views to scroll as one. This is what I implemented but I do not see any scroll, can someone tell me what is wrong

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gcm_list_item_header_bg"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            >
        </ListView>



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_disabled_activities"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Use RecyclerView instead of ListView. RecyclerView and NestedScrollView are being developed for working together.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from nestedScrollView `android:fillViewport="true"`

**Edit**

If you want to see full height of each listView follow this link... and use this method.. **to set height of listview based on children**  [listview and recyclerview doesnot wrap content with count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110244/listview-and-recyclerview-doesnot-wrap-content-with-count/48110309#48110309)

Comment: If I remove fillViewport, I will not see the list. I will see only one item in the each list.